# Python Scope: Pipe is broken - UiPath Studio

Tags: python, python-3.x, uipath, uipath-studio

I have been researching on this for a while but I couldn't find a solution.

I am using UiPath Studio and trying to run python script using the "Run Python Script" activity. However, there is a pipe is broken error.

I know this error is generic so I tried to zoom into the error through Try Catch. I am importing only 4 modules into the script:

```
import time
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import csv
import gspread
```

"import gspread" seems to be causing the error since when I shift the rest outside of the try catch block, there is no issues. I have checked that gspread is installed and I ran it on IDLE to make sure it's working.

I am using Python 3.9

Please help me :(